# open source flash pain \ sketchpad

Tags: flash

I have seen this question asked here a few times, but most question didn't recieve an answer. I'm trying my luck, has anybody heard of any such tool?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any open source flash paint (i guess it is paint?) or sketchpad app. But on he same time I also do not see much use of such an app, If you are referring to just sketching & coloring online sitting in a website when even the simplest of tools do the job.

But if you are rather interested in code, than an app I could show some code of a small flash app I made for my nephew (who is the only one who ever used it :P). Please let me know.

Comment: loxxy that sounds great! I would really appericiate it if you could.
please mail me if you will to : vonjohn@walla.com

Thank you!!

Comment: Hey, I have mailed you the flash fla along with details. Here is a preview of the compiled swf:
http://webng.com/ajayvishnu/paintgame.html